# Java LayoutManager Reevaluation

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

Do Java layout managers re-evaluate managed container dimensions on every paint() call or do they only re-evaluate when the owned panel (the panel that uses the layout manager) changes dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Layout managers only re-evaluate when the Container is invalid. See [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html).validate and invalidate